# Lag pandas time series on nearest date

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, lag

I have a time series as below:

[image]

I would like to lag column A by one month by choosing the **nearest** value to (t - 1 Mth).

For example, A', being the lagged column A, would have for row 1991-02-27, the value corresponding to 1991-01-30.

What would be the Pandas solution for this?

Comment: For the examples you got, can you add the expected date?

Comment: The expected date is always the nearest to (t - 1 mth) so: 1991-03-13 -> 1991-02-13, 1991-02-27 -> 1991-01-30 etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify one month lag by `30` days lag and use [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) with parameter `method='nearest'`:

```
df = df.reindex(df.index - pd.to_timedelta(30, unit='d'), method='nearest')
```